# RoR - ArgumentError when setup private key for Let's Encrypt API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, lets-encrypt

I'd like to use the gem [rails-letsencrypt](https://github.com/elct9620/rails-letsencrypt) to generate SSL certificates dynamically, with my RoR application.

I'm following the instructions, and in the step "Setup private key for Let's Encrypt API" I got an error.

after I changed the gemfile and runned install migrations, I am tried to setup private key for Let's Encrypt API. But, after answer the questions like that:

- Do you want to use in production environment? [y/N]: y
- Where you to save private key [/myapp/config/letsencrypt.key]: [ENTER]
- Overwrite /myapp/config/letsencrypt.key? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqh] y
- What email you want to register: myname@mayemail.com

I got this error:

```
/home/computer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/acme-client-2.0.0/lib/acme/client.rb:31:in 'initialize': unknown keyword: endpoint (ArgumentError) from 
/home/computer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-letsencrypt-0.5.4/lib/letsencrypt.rb:24:in 'new' from 
/home/computer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-letsencrypt-0.5.4/lib/letsencrypt.rb:24:in 'client' from 
/home/computer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-letsencrypt-0.5.4/lib/letsencrypt.rb:52:in 'register' from 
/home/computer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-letsencrypt-0.5.4/lib/generators/lets_encrypt/register_generator.rb:49:in 'register_email' from 
/home/computer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-letsencrypt-0.5.4/lib/generators/lets_encrypt/register_generator.rb:16:in 'register'
```

I don't know what I'm forgetting. Someone can help me?

```
Using development env (localhost)
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 4.2.1
rails-letsencrypt 0.5.4
acme-client 2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner of repository creates a patch to solve. [See the reference](https://github.com/elct9620/rails-letsencrypt/issues/8).

After that, I just updated the gem to version 0.5.5 and works fine.